# Html auto refresh table

Tags: php, html, ajax, html-table, partial-page-refresh

I wrote this simple code and this table which I have connected to mysql database. It fetches the data I inserted in my database what I want is for the page to automatically refresh on its own without having to refresh the whole page.
My Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Whats Up?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="Register.php">Register</a> <a href="login.php">Login</a>


<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('summerinstitute');
    $query="SELECT * FROM students";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    echo "<table border=\"1\">";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['fname'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['lname'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['username'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['Email'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";}
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to refresh only the table results? On an event perhaps? You'll need to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript and some ajax implementation to only `refresh` a part of the page.

For example with jQuery:

php page1.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Whats Up?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="Register.php">Register</a> <a href="login.php">Login</a>
        <?php include_once('page2.php')?>
    </body>
</html>
```

php page2.php:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('summerinstitute');
    $query="SELECT * FROM students";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    echo "<table border='1' id='tableID'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['fname'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['lname'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['username'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['Email'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";}
    ?>
```

Javascript on page1.php (put it in the header):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(function(){
       $.get('page2.php',{},function(data){
           $('#tableID').replaceWith($(data));  
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look on

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

it will answer your questions

Answer (score 0):

Ajax

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Ajax()
        {
            var
                $http,
                $self = arguments.callee;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                    $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
                } catch(e) {
                    $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }
            }

            if ($http) {
                $http.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                        document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
                        setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 10000);
                    }
                };
                $http.open('GET', 'random.php' + '?' + new Date().getTime(), true);
                $http.send(null);
            }

        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() {Ajax();}, 10000);
    </script>
    <div id="ReloadThis">Default text</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
setTimeout(function refreshTable() {
$.ajax({
    url:'/some-script.php',
    dataType:'html',
    data:{
       someparam:'someval'
    },
    success:function(data) {
        $('#yourTable').find('tbody').empty().append(data);
        setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
    }
 });
}, 5000); //every 5 seconds refresh
```

Comment: I like to be more specific using $.ajax over $.post or $.get

Comment: This will also refresh the table after 5 seconds once the ajax request is complete

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much with PHP, but you probably want that PHP that creates the table on it's own separate page, and then use AJAX to get the data whenever you want to refresh the table. If you use dojo you could do something like this.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //call this function whenever you want to update the table
    function updateTable()
    {
        dojo.xhrGet({
            url: 'my_table.php',
            handleAs: 'text',
            load: function(data) {
                dojo.byId('table').innerHTML = data;
            });
    }
    </script>
    <title>Whats Up?</title>
</head>
<body onload='updateTable()'>
    <a href="Register.php">Register</a> <a href="login.php">Login</a>

<div id='table'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my_table.php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('summerinstitute');
    $query="SELECT * FROM students";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    echo "<table border=\"1\">";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['fname'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['lname'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['username'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['Email'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";}
    ?>
```